# Issue with web crawler: IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, index-error

I am making a web crawler. I'm not using scrapy or anything, I'm trying to have my script do most things. I have tried doing a search for the issue however I can't seem to find anything that helps with the error. I've tried switching around some of the variable to try and narrow down the problem. I am getting an error on line 24 saying IndexError: string index out of range. The functions run on the first url, (the original url) then the second and fail on the third in the original array. I'm lost, any help would be appreciated greatly! Note, I'm only printing all of them for testing, I'll eventually have them printed to a text file.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# creating requests from user input
url = raw_input("Please enter a domain to crawl, without the 'http://www' part : ")

def makeRequest(url):
    r = requests.get('http://' + url)
    # Adding in BS4 for finding a tags in HTML
    soup =  BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    # Writes a as the link found in the href
    output = soup.find_all('a')
    return output


def makeFilter(link):
    # Creating array for our links
    found_link = []
    for a in link:
        a = a.get('href')
        a_string = str(a)

        # if statement to filter our links
        if a_string[0] == '/': # this is the line with the error
            # Realtive Links
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'http://' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'https://' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site with SSL
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'http://www.' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site
            found_link.append(a_string)

        if 'https://www.' + url in a_string:
            # Links from the same site with SSL
            found_link.append(a_string)
        #else:  
        #   found_link.write(a_string + '\n') # testing only
    output = found_link

    return output   

# Function for removing duplicates
def remove_duplicates(values):
    output = []
    seen = set()
    for value in values:
        if value not in seen:
            output.append(value)
            seen.add(value)
    return output

# Run the function with our list in this order -> Makes the request -> Filters the links -> Removes duplicates
def createURLList(values):
    requests = makeRequest(values)
    new_list = makeFilter(requests)
    filtered_list = remove_duplicates(new_list)

    return filtered_list

result = createURLList(url)

# print result

# for verifying and crawling resulting pages
for b in result:
    sub_directories = createURLList(url + b)
    crawler = []
    crawler.append(sub_directories)

    print crawler
```

Comment: Have you `print`ed `a_string`? It's an empty string.

Comment: I did try that, but I'm getting that same thing although it prints three strings and then errors out with the same error.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you only have `print crawler` in your code. Try `print "this is string_a", a` right underneath `a_string = str(a)`. It is almost certainly blank.

Comment: OK I did that, although it's not empty I get the print out of all the links that it found.

Comment: I honestly don't know of any other way to get `IndexError: string index out of range` unless you had `this is string a ` and nothing after it printed out immediately before the error. You could try `import sys` and do `sys.stdout.flush()` right after the print statement and before `if a_string[0] == '/'` to check you see the last the last `print` statement properly.

Comment: I did that, thanks for the suggestion, I'm still having issues, but at least I have something I can look into, I was lost before. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `a_string = str(a)` try adding:

```
if not a_string:
  continue
```

Comment: This actually looked like it may have cleared the issue, it still fails about eighteen links down but the error is different. Thanks! Would that mean that it is an empty string, somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, it means `a_string` is falsy (`""`, `None`, `False`, `0`, etc), but almost certainly an empty string.

Comment: I'm sorry of this is a stupid question would it be better if I didn't have the string function? Or should I keep digging?

Comment: @GeorgeOffley It shouldn't really matter. Where/what is the error now?

Comment: This is the new error. As I said, the script runs for about eighteen of the links.

requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='python.orghttp', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //python.org/dev/peps/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f297330f110>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))

Comment: @GeorgeOffley Ah, ok. Well you're clearly getting an invalid url... `python.orghttp` is not legit. That is, `.orghttp` is not a valid TLD. You should  add a `print("Trying...", url)` to the top of your `makeRequest` function and it will make it clearer where it's going wrong. That said, this is outside the scope of your original question. So ideally you'll accept this answer (click the checkbox next to it) and create a new question if you continue to have unrelated problems. Good luck!